# Windows 7 Weird Sound Issue

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

I have a Toshiba Satellite P755-S5390 running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-Bit. I have encountered a weird issue with the sound on my system. When I plug in my speakers, or anything for that matter, into the headphone jack, no sound whatsoever plays. However, when there is nothing plugged into the computer's headphone jack, the sound works perfectly on the built-in speakers.

One of the weirdest things about this problem is that it occurs randomly, and sometimes it just seems to fix itself with a restart, but other times, even that won't work. I have reinstalled Windows to no avail. The next morning, though, it fixed itself. Another odd property to this sound issue is that I also have a partition of my drive with Zorin OS 8 64-Bit and there are zero problems with sound, and my Nexus 5 also works perfectly when plugged in to all of the devices malfunctioning with Windows. The computer also thinks that it is playing sound, while no sound is being put out.

I have tried:

- Restarting the machine
- Reinstalling Windows
- Updating my sound drivers
- Running windows troubleshooting
- Changing properties in the 'Sound' option in the Control Panel

If anyone can give any advice that can fix this, that would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Screenies: [Imgur Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0CTz.jpg)

Comment: Are any of these screenshots while the headphones are plugged in? The mixer screenshot, for example, has the speaker icon instead of the headphones icon.